# How to select 3 independent tuples from an SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to select the top X from a table where X is an integer variable. SELECT TOP 2 * FROM CUSTOMERS; I want to know is there any way to select each individual tuple on it's own? is this possible? To select each one individually?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you mean by *select 3 independent tuples*, but of course you can select individual tuples if you can identify them somehow. The `where`clause is what you want to use; the basic form is this:

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE column = value
```

for example

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 1
```

would get you the name of the customer with id 1.